# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript

код рабочий но в браузере выдается ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

сам код:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navbar').on('click', 'a', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top;
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 500);
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navbar').on('click', 'a', function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset();
            
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top.top}, 500);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="block" id="navbar">navbar</a>
```